# How to share an object between two asp.net applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, projects-and-solutions

I have two applications one is Mvc another one is WebAPI. Is it possible at all share object between both applications.

For instance I created `Test` class in separate library:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static string WebApi { get; set; }
    public static string Mvc { get; set; }
}
```

And set `Test.Mvc = "Mvc"` in `Application_Start` of MVC application and `Test.WebApi= "WebAPI"`in `Application_Start` of WebAPI application. But `WebApi` property is empty within MVC application.

Maybe I missing some attribute or some setting and is that possible at all?

Comment: Separate applications will not share values like that. They are separate processes in windows and as such have memory barriers. You have to use IPC (inter process communication) to send data back and forth between them, or maybe something simple like write to a text file or database that they both can access.

Comment: The easiest way is to store the object (serialized) in a database field or an Xml file.